# How do I make a select statement display as a list when the website is fullscreen?

Tags: jquery, html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I'm using Bootstrap 3 to develop a responsive website, and where there's plenty of screen space I'd like a list of distributors on my menu to the left.

Unfortunately this does not look very nice on a mobile device, so I changed the option to a select statement for the mobile platform. When I look at the page again on the desktop site, there's just too much white space not being used, so I'd like to use some functionality to only display this as a select statement for smaller screen sizes.

I viewed a tutorial here (http://css-tricks.com/convert-menu-to-dropdown/) that works, but I'd prefer to have this change without redundant code to create an additional menu that's hidden until the screen size changes. Any ideas?

Also, the select tag must be used as it's recognized by mobile devices to pull up the select method on the phone.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're question is extremely confusing in terms of what you actually want to display, but the gist of it is, you need to use @media queries to specify CSS rules which will only be used at specific screen sizes.  BS3 has built-in support for several screen dimension breakpoints which you can use out of the box (http://getbootstrap.com/css/#responsive-utilities) although it's easy enough to add more.

It sounds like you want to  do something like this:

```
  @media (min-width: @screen-tablet) {
    //rules to display the option as select statement (whatever that means)
  }
```

**UPDATE:**

Ok I re-read your question and want to add that there's no way to write code which will automagically change from links into a dropdown based on screen size.  You basically have two ways you can do it.  The first way I have already showed, which is to create separate menus and hide or show one of them based on screen size using media queries.  The other way is to write Javascript which will dynamically generate the correct form of the menu and use window resize event handlers to fire the appropriate code.  Each method has its advantages and disadvantages.

Comment: Sorry for the confusion, and thanks for the response. It looks like just adding a separate but hidden menu is the general online consensus.